# A fast algorithm for determining timeshare requests

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I am writing a program that will simulate how members of a certain timeshare will request their apartments. The apartments are only available for certain 'events' throughout the year, and the events each have different durations (counted in days). For each event, there are a number of apartments available, which are divided into groups according to cost (points per day).

We may also have the situation that some of the apartments are already rented out, so it is possible that certain events cannot admit a certain apartment type.

Now I want a member to request apartments according to this strategy:

- Maximizing the number of total event days is first priority.
- Maximizing the number of points spent is second priority (so the user requests the best possible apartment that he/she can afford and still have as many days as possible).
- The total cost of the requested apartments cannot exceed the total amount of available points for that user.
- Obviously, if there are no more apartments of a given type for a certain event, the user should not request that particular apartment/event combo.

I am wondering whether the problem is similar to the problem described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

in that it (I suppose) possible to frame this as a matrix problem where each entry has a cost associated with it.

However, the difference is that for my problem, I am allowed to use the same apartment for several events - it's not 'spent' once it has been used for one event. Also, the cost per entry is not really one-dimensional, since each event/apartment combo both has a number of days associated with it *and* a number of points - both of which should be maximized (but with priority given to the number of days).

As an example, let's say there are three apartment types, costing 75, 100, and 125 points per day, and three events, with a duration of 2, 10, and 4 days. Let's further say many of the apartments are taken, so the availability matrix looks like this:

```
                  cost
             75    100   125
       2    True False True
 days  10   False False True
       4    True False True
```

Let's also say the user has 1250 points available. The solution, in this case, would be that the user requests the 10-day event with the 125-point apartment and nothing else.

The brute-force way of doing this would perhaps be a recursive algorithm:

- Let n be the number of events you are currently trying
- Find all combinations of events and apartments, and calculate the combo that maximizes the number of days, then the number of points spent (this will both include all permutations of n events, but also the number of ways 3 apartment types can be assigned to n events).
- Let n=n-1

This will quickly become overwhelming when the number of events goes up, I think, so I am wondering whether there are any algorithms that can solve this in a less expensive way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to a library for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming you could try throwing this at it.

Even if you have only one choice of cost for each event, so that you are just trying to chose combinations of events that cover as many total days as possible without going over budget, I think this reduces to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem. This means that it is unlikely to be solved exactly by a worst case polynomial time algorithm such as the Hungarian algorithm.

Comment: Yes, the knapsack problem is more closely related to my problem than what I first suggested. The only difference is that I also want to maximize the weight while still being below the weight limit. I will see if I can modify the algorithm. Alternatively, once the solution to optimize the number of days is found, I can more easily loop through the apartments available for the chosen events (since they shouldn't be changed once the optimal number of days has been found).